Horror movie about a radiated man taking revenge of people by touching them
When I was 11 (22 yrs ago) I watched a horror movie that freaked me out and kept me from sleeping a whole year! Now I want to watch it again.
It's about a radiated man who wants to take revenge on people. He just kills them by touching them. My memory fails me but I remember these scenes:

He touches a couple kissing in a car at the begining of movie and they die.
Many other crime scenes take place in the movie and some investigation happens by a detective.
After each crime scene a screenshot image in black and white is taken. 
We never see the radiated man all through the movie until the very end. When the crime scenes take place we sort of see it through his eyes. It is not very violent.
At the very end he is captured and emprisoned in a nuclear powerplant where his colleagues or people seem to know about him. At this point we finally see him, he is greenish and bold and does not appear to be aggressive.
Movie ends with the powerplant exploding somehow...

It was so long ago I can't remember much else and some of the info there may be altered.
This movie is somewhere from late 80s or very early 90s.

You might also be interested in Liquid Sky, a cult movie from the 1982, which utilizes a similar technique for revenge (warning: Liquid Sky is quite salty--not for kids!)

Hey @Maro have you had a chance to look at the full movie I put in the answer?

I believe you may be looking for the 1990 film Burndown. The story involves a radioactive serial killer who operates in areas near a nuclear plant. I also think the powerplant explodes at the end of the movie, just like you mention in your question.
I can't remember if it does a black and white image, but I'm pretty sure it does indeed do a freeze-frame shot at the peak of each murder.

Women are killed in a small town near a condemned nuclear power plant. The bodies turn out to be very radioactive. The sheriff and a female reporter start to investigate.

Here is the VHS cover with an additional description:

Here is the film on Youtube. Hopefully, it's the one you're looking for. 



Wow nice one ;-)
It seems to be it! The description and plot seems to be identical. However, I can't seem to verify. I have been searching all day for a YouTube video or trailer or a stream website with the movie of any place selling a DVD copy.. no where to be found! I checked out the YouTube video you posted. It was such a long time ago that that video really doesn't ring a bell. I'd need to see some of the parts I remember which are mostly those I described. I guess they screen freeze shots upon the murders may not have been black and white after all. But once again it was so long ago. Any

@Maro You might want to register one of your accounts and merge them together following the procedure described here. This will enable you to take full control of your content, including editing it, commenting on it, as well as voting and accepting any possible answers.

@Maro - Here is the movie on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8UtSuZfDFI

There was another movie called THE INCREDIBLE MELTING MAN:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Melting_Man
